# How to plot a draggable polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib

Regarding [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html#draggable-rectangle-exercise) matplotlib example that plots draggable rectangles I tried to do the same with polygons.

So far I am able to plot a polygon and drag it somewhere on the canvas. If I release the mouse button I won't be able to move the polygon again and thats my problem. I would like to drag and drop the polygon by every mouse press as often as I want to.

I also noticed that after moving the polygon I can still click on the position where the polygon used to be and drag it again. So the initial `geometry` must be saved somewhere but I guess it should be overwritten instead.

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments below I will add a patch instead of a collection as I will only plot a single polygon (see old code commented out). Additionally I closed the polygon to demonstrate that you can drag the patch only by clicking inside the polygon but not by clicking on its edges.

If I want to drag the polygon a second time it automatically jumps back to its initial position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
#from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

class DraggablePolygon:
    lock = None
    def __init__(self, polygon):
        self.poly = polygon
        self.press = None

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        self.cidpress = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
        if event.inaxes != self.poly.axes: return
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not None: return
        contains, attrd = self.poly.contains(event)
        if not contains: return
        x0, y0 = geometry[0]
        self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata
        DraggablePolygon.lock = self

    def on_motion(self, event):
        'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not self:
            return
        if event.inaxes != self.poly.axes: return
        x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        xdx = [i+dx for i,_ in geometry]
        ydy = [i+dy for _,i in geometry]
        self.newGeometry = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(xdx, ydy)]
        #polygon = Polygon(self.newGeometry, closed=False, fill=False, linewidth=3, color='#F97306')
        #patches = []
        #patches.append(polygon)
        #plt.cla()
        #p = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)
        #ax.add_collection(p)

        self.poly.set_xy(newGeometry)  # this will set the vertices of the polygon

        self.poly.figure.canvas.draw()

    def on_release(self, event):
        'on release we reset the press data'
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not self:
            return

        self.press = None
        DraggablePolygon.lock = None

    def disconnect(self):
        'disconnect all the stored connection ids'
        self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

geometry = [[0.0,0.0],[0.1,0.05],[0.2,0.15],[0.3,0.20],[0.4,0.25],[0.5,0.30],
        [0.6,0.25],[0.7,0.15],[0.8,0.05],[0.9,0.025],[1.0,0.0]]

patches = []
polygon = plt.Polygon(geometry, closed=True, fill=False, linewidth=3, color='#F97306')
#patches.append(polygon)
#p = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)
#ax.add_collection(p)

ax.add_patch(polygon)

dp = DraggablePolygon(polygon)
dp.connect()

plt.show()
```

I assume that the definition of `geometry` and `newGeometry` has to be on a different position inside the code but after a few attempts I couldn't find a working solution. Does anyone find the mistakes I made?

Comment: You create a totally new PatchCollection each time the mouse is moved? That surely can't be the solution. May I ask, why do you use a collection at all for a single polygon?

Comment: Honest answer: Because I didn't know how to do it otherwise. I am a beginner and try to learn from examples (as linked in my question). Yes, I will be using only a single polygon so I assume I really don't need a collection. When the mouse is moved I only want to update the polygon's geometry and redraw it.

Comment: Ok, so for the rectangle you have `rect.set_x`, this does not exist for a polygon. Instead you need to set the vertices all at once via [`polygon.set_xy`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon.set_xy).

Comment: That's very helpfull! There still remains the problem that I cannot drag the polygon a second or third time from its actual position. Maybe its because I call `geometry` in `on_press` instead of `newGeometry`...

Comment: Yes, `geometry` isn't defined inside the class, so it will always be the initial position.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest One more question: How can I switch from clicking inside the polygon to clicking on its contour to move it? Maybe by using something else than `self.poly.axes`? Or do I have to open a whole new question on SO for an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to determine if a click is on the edge. Possibly you need to use an additional line to catch a click on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments below the question helped to find a working code finally. Maybe it's not the best and most pythonic way but it does what I want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

class DraggablePolygon:
    lock = None
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')
        self.press = None

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.geometry = [[0.0,0.0],[0.1,0.05],[0.2,0.15],[0.3,0.20],[0.4,0.25],[0.5,0.30],
                    [0.6,0.25],[0.7,0.15],[0.8,0.05],[0.9,0.025],[1.0,0.0]]
        self.newGeometry = []
        poly = plt.Polygon(self.geometry, closed=True, fill=False, linewidth=3, color='#F97306')
        ax.add_patch(poly)
        self.poly = poly

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        print('connect')
        self.cidpress = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
        'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
        print('on_press')
        if event.inaxes != self.poly.axes: return
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not None: return
        contains, attrd = self.poly.contains(event)
        if not contains: return

        if not self.newGeometry:
            x0, y0 = self.geometry[0]
        else:
            x0, y0 = self.newGeometry[0]

        self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata
        DraggablePolygon.lock = self

    def on_motion(self, event):
        'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not self:
            return
        if event.inaxes != self.poly.axes: return
        x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress

        xdx = [i+dx for i,_ in self.geometry]
        ydy = [i+dy for _,i in self.geometry]
        self.newGeometry = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(xdx, ydy)]
        self.poly.set_xy(self.newGeometry)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.draw()

    def on_release(self, event):
        'on release we reset the press data'
        print('on_release')
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not self:
            return

        self.press = None
        DraggablePolygon.lock = None
        self.geometry = self.newGeometry


    def disconnect(self):
        'disconnect all the stored connection ids'
        print('disconnect')
        self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)


dp = DraggablePolygon()
dp.connect()

plt.show()
```