# How to drag, drop and rotate any shape by mouse click or scroll wheel?

Tags: python, matplotlib

By posting a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770331/how-to-plot-a-draggable-polygon) I learned how to drag and drop a shape which works without any complaints. Now I am trying to add a function that rotates this shape by using the scroll wheel.

So far the program does what it is supposed to but unfortunately with intolerable inaccuracies. The two main issues are:

### 1. Unwanted reset of rotated shape after translation:

By dragging and dropping an already rotated shape the shape rotates back to a zero degree angle. If I use the scroll wheel again the shape jumps back to where it's supposed to be.

My suggestion was to change the lines:

```
    xdx = [i+dx for i,_ in self.geometry]
    ydy = [i+dy for _,i in self.geometry]
```

to:

```
    xdx = [i+dx for i,_ in self.newGeometry]
    ydy = [i+dy for _,i in self.newGeometry]
```

hoping that it wouldn't plot the initial shape then. Unfortunately it leads to a kind of "quadratic" translation.

### 2. Shape does not rotate about it's local origin:

The line:

```
   x0, y0 = self.newGeometry[0]
```

defines the shape's local origin which is supposed to be the center of rotation. So this coordinate is not allowed to change during any rotation. By comparing these coordinates before and after rotation I noticed that there is a steadily increasing deviation.

The full MWE consists of six functions provided below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class DraggablePolygon:
    lock = None
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')
        self.press = None
        self.angle = 0

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.geometry = [[0.0,0.0],[0.1,0.05],[0.2,0.15],[0.3,0.20],[0.4,0.25],[0.5,0.30],
                [0.6,0.25],[0.7,0.15],[0.8,0.05],[0.9,0.025],[1.0,0.0]]

        self.newGeometry = [[0.0,0.0]]

        poly = plt.Polygon(self.geometry, closed=True, fill=False, linewidth=3, color='#F97306')
        ax.add_patch(poly)
        self.poly = poly

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        print('connect')
        self.cidpress = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
        self.cidscroll = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
                'scroll_event', self.rotate_on_scroll)


    def on_press(self, event):
        'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
        print('on_press')
        if event.inaxes != self.poly.axes: return
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not None: return
        contains, attrd = self.poly.contains(event)
        if not contains: return

        x0, y0 = self.newGeometry[0]
        print('x0 = '+str(x0)+', '+'y0 = '+str(y0)+' -> on_press')
        self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata
        DraggablePolygon.lock = self

    def on_motion(self, event):
        'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not self:
            return
        if event.inaxes != self.poly.axes: return
        x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress

        xdx = [i+dx for i,_ in self.geometry]
        ydy = [i+dy for _,i in self.geometry]

        self.newGeometry = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(xdx, ydy)]
        self.poly.set_xy(self.newGeometry)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.draw()

    def on_release(self, event):
        'on release we reset the press data'
        print('on_release')
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not self:
            return

        self.press = None
        DraggablePolygon.lock = None
        self.geometry = self.newGeometry
        print('x0 = '+str(self.geometry[0][0])+', '+'y0 = '+str(self.geometry[0][1])+' -> on_release')
        self.poly.set_xy(self.geometry)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.draw()

    def rotate_on_scroll(self, event, degree=1):
        if event.button == 'up':
            self.angle += degree*(np.pi/180)
        elif event.button == 'down':
            self.angle -= degree*(np.pi/180)

        x0, y0 = self.newGeometry[0]
        print('x0 = '+str(x0)+', '+'y0 = '+str(y0)+' -> pre_scroll')

        qx = []
        qy = []
        for i in range(len(self.geometry)):
            qx.append(x0 + np.cos(self.angle) * (self.geometry[i][0] - x0)
        - np.sin(self.angle) * (self.geometry[i][1] - y0))
            qy.append(y0 + np.sin(self.angle) * (self.geometry[i][0] - y0)
        + np.cos(self.angle) * (self.geometry[i][1] - y0))
        self.newGeometry = np.column_stack((qx, qy))

        print('x0 = '+str(self.newGeometry[0][0])+', '+'y0 = '+str(self.newGeometry[0][1])+' -> after_scroll')
        print('delta_x = '+str(x0-self.newGeometry[0][0])+', '+'delta_y = '+str(y0-self.newGeometry[0][1])+' -> deviation during scroll')
        self.poly.set_xy(self.newGeometry)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.draw()

dp = DraggablePolygon()
dp.connect()

plt.show()
```

I expect the shape to rotate without any "jumps" and about it's local origin. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that the role of `newGeometry` and `geometry` aren't clearly defined here. The following should work though.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class DraggablePolygon:
    lock = None
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')
        self.press = None
        self.angle = 0

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.geometry = [[0.0,0.0],[0.1,0.05],[0.2,0.15],[0.3,0.20],[0.4,0.25],[0.5,0.30],
                [0.6,0.25],[0.7,0.15],[0.8,0.05],[0.9,0.025],[1.0,0.0]]

        self.newGeometry = self.geometry

        poly = plt.Polygon(self.geometry, closed=True, fill=False, linewidth=3, color='#F97306')
        ax.add_patch(poly)
        self.poly = poly

    def connect(self):
        'connect to all the events we need'
        print('connect')
        self.cidpress = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
        self.cidscroll = self.poly.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
                'scroll_event', self.rotate_on_scroll)


    def on_press(self, event):
        'on button press we will see if the mouse is over us and store some data'
        print('on_press')
        if event.inaxes != self.poly.axes: return
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not None: return
        contains, attrd = self.poly.contains(event)
        if not contains: return
        self.geometry = self.newGeometry
        x0, y0 = self.newGeometry[0]
        print('x0 = '+str(x0)+', '+'y0 = '+str(y0)+' -> on_press')
        self.press = x0, y0, event.xdata, event.ydata
        DraggablePolygon.lock = self

    def on_motion(self, event):
        'on motion we will move the rect if the mouse is over us'
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not self:
            return
        if event.inaxes != self.poly.axes: return
        x0, y0, xpress, ypress = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress

        xdx = [i+dx for i,_ in self.geometry]
        ydy = [i+dy for _,i in self.geometry]

        self.newGeometry = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(xdx, ydy)]
        self.poly.set_xy(self.newGeometry)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.draw()

    def on_release(self, event):
        'on release we reset the press data'
        print('on_release')
        if DraggablePolygon.lock is not self:
            return

        self.press = None
        DraggablePolygon.lock = None
        self.geometry = self.newGeometry
        print('x0 = '+str(self.geometry[0][0])+', '+'y0 = '+str(self.geometry[0][1])+' -> on_release')
        self.poly.set_xy(self.geometry)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.draw()

    def rotate_on_scroll(self, event, degree=1):
        if event.button == 'up':
            self.angle += degree*(np.pi/180)
        elif event.button == 'down':
            self.angle -= degree*(np.pi/180)

        x0, y0 = self.newGeometry[0]
        print('x0 = '+str(x0)+', '+'y0 = '+str(y0)+' -> pre_scroll')

        qx = []
        qy = []
        for i in range(len(self.geometry)):
            qx.append(x0 + np.cos(self.angle) * (self.newGeometry[i][0] - x0)
                        - np.sin(self.angle) * (self.newGeometry[i][1] - y0))
            qy.append(y0 + np.sin(self.angle) * (self.newGeometry[i][0] - x0)
                        + np.cos(self.angle) * (self.newGeometry[i][1] - y0))
        self.newGeometry = np.column_stack((qx, qy))

        print('x0 = '+str(self.newGeometry[0][0])+', '+'y0 = '+str(self.newGeometry[0][1])+' -> after_scroll')
        print('delta_x = '+str(x0-self.newGeometry[0][0])+', '+'delta_y = '+str(y0-self.newGeometry[0][1])+' -> deviation during scroll')
        self.poly.set_xy(self.newGeometry)
        self.poly.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.angle = 0

dp = DraggablePolygon()
dp.connect()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer solves the first issue. Thanks! But the shape's local origin does not coincide with the center of rotation. The source of this inaccuracy lies in the calculation of `qx` and `qy`. If `x0` and `y0` are both 0 the deviation also is 0. Only if I move the shape away from the global origin there will be a deviation in the local origin after rotation. Could this be caused by a rounding error which I won't be able to influence?

Comment: I always want to rotate about `self.geometry[0]` respectively `self.newGeometry[0]` if there has been a rotation already. `self.geometry[0]` or `self.newGeometry[0]` must not change after a rotation.

Comment: Now I got it! Even with your edited answer it took me a while to see that I mistook `x0` for `y0` while calculating `qy`. Thanks a lot!